# creating a composer custom class

Tags: composer-php

I'm new to composer. But i'm trying to create a custom class that installs a dependent package in the root directory of my project rather than in the vendor directory. I tried to follow the example on getcomposer.org but I'm getting the following errors:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'jeffreycwitt\Composer\LombardPressInstaller' not found in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallerInstaller.php on line 100

Fatal error: Class 'jeffreycwitt\Composer\LombardPressInstaller' not found in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallerInstaller.php on line 100
```

Below is the composer.json and custom class I made. Can you see any problems???

composer.json

```
   {
        "name": "jeffreycwitt/lombardpress-installer",
        "type": "composer-installer",
        "license": "MIT",
        "autoload": {
            "psr-0": {"jeffreycwitt\\Composer": ""}
        },
        "extra": {
            "class": "jeffreycwitt\\Composer\\LombardPressInstaller"
        }
    }
```

lombardpressInstaller.php

```
namespace jeffreycwitt\Composer;

use Composer\Package\PackageInterface;
use Composer\Installer\LibraryInstaller;

class LombardPressInstaller extends LibraryInstaller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getInstallPath(PackageInterface $package)
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function supports($packageType)
    {
        return 'jeffreycwitt-lombardpress' === $packageType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My autoload part looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "wmdb\\T3cmsComposerInstaller": "Classes/"
    }
},
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
/Classes/
     wmdb/
        T3cmsComposerInstaller/
            [Code classes go here]
```

Does this help?